# Solving integral with Gauss' Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

From Youtube video:

*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_PRmeOFODw&list=PLVMgvCDIRy1wzJcFNGw7t4tehgzhFtBpm&index=11* 13:40

There is a concept that I can't get.
The integral
$$\int_0^\pi{\ln(\sin\theta)d\theta}$$
is solved by following steps
$$=\int_0^\pi{\ln({1\over2i}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}))d\theta}$$
$$=\int_0^\pi{-\ln(2i)+\ln(e^{i\theta}(1-e^{-2i\theta}))d\theta}$$
$$=\int_0^\pi{-\ln(2i)+i\theta+\ln(1-e^{-2i\theta})d\theta}$$
$$=-\pi(\ln2+{\pi\over2}i)+{i\pi^2\over2}+\int_0^\pi{\ln(1-e^{-2i\theta})d\theta}$$
$$=-\pi(\ln2+{\pi\over2}i)+{i\pi^2\over2}+\lim_{r\to0^+}\int_0^\pi{\ln(1-re^{-2i\theta})d\theta}$$
$$=-\pi\ln2$$
There's the place that I don't understand:

It transferred
$$\int_0^\pi{\ln(1-e^{-2i\theta})d\theta}$$
into the form with a limit outside,
$$\lim_{r\to0^+}\int_0^\pi{\ln(1-re^{-2i\theta})d\theta}$$
But why it is valid to put a limit in front of the integral? Isn't it will be integrating $0$ after putting the limit but it was originally a non-zero function? The video has explained that it is because $\ln\theta$ is not analytic on $0$, but it doesn't show that it is valid to put a limit.